# Sum divisors function in Python

Tags: python

This is an example for a number(45) that the sum_divisors end with 0. For example: 45->33->15->9->4->3->1->0
Some numbers like (6) repeat themselves until no end..
I have to build a function which checks if the number is the first case(returns ture) or not..

The function is_finite returns False for num=4 .any idea why?

```
def is_finite(num):
    x=0
    while(num!=0 and x!=num):
        x=num
        num=sum_divisors(num)

    if num==0 :
        return True
    else:
        return False

def sum_divisors(n):
    sum=1
    x=int(n**0.5)
    for i in range(2,(x//1)+1):
        if n%i==0:
            sum=sum+i
        if n%i==0 and n/i!=i:
            sum=sum+(n/i)            
    return int(sum)
```

Answer (score 3):

To return true, sum_divisors would have to return 0.  But the sum variable starts at 1 and only adds positive numbers, so the function will never return 0.

Answer (score 3):

Start by defining a `get_divisors` function:

```
def get_divisors(num):
    return [i for i in range(1, num) if num % i == 0]
```

Then your `sum_divisors` function is simply:

```
def sum_divisors(num):
    return sum(get_divisors(num))
```

When crafting your `is_finite` function, you will need to **cache** your previous results and check if a number is repeated.

```
def is_finite(num):
    previous = []

    while num != 0:
        if num in previous:
            return False

        previous.append(num)
        num = sum_divisors(num)

    return True
```

If you don't do this, you'll get an *infinite loop*.

Comment: Note that get_divisors takes O(N) time, while the method in the question is O(sqrt(N)).  It's probably not too hard to modify get_divisors to be O(sqrt(N))

Comment: The thing is; I have to make a function which has O(sqrt(N)) interactions.

Comment: You can use your original `sum_divisors` or change the range I use above to `range(1, int(sqrt(num) + 1))`, calculate corresponding tuples (i, num/i) and then flatten. Hmm though you would need to take care that you didn't accidentally have a duplicate number in the case of a perfect square, i.e. `(5,5)` for `num = 25`.